# Hashie::Rash being converted to string instead on Json or hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I am using an API whose reply is in form of Hashie::Rash. an example:

```
country = #<Hashie::Rash confidence="99" geoname_id=3175395 iso_code="IT" names=#<Hashie::Rash de="Italien" en="Italy" es="Italia" fr="Italie" ja="イタリア共和国" pt_br="Itália" ru="Италия" zh_cn="意大利">>
```

country.class = Hashie::Rash

I want to convert this to Json, to look like

```
{"iso_code":"IT","names": {"pt_br":"Itália","es":"Italia","ru":"Италия","en":"Italy","zh_cn":"意大 利","fr":"Italie","de":"Italien","ja":"イタリア共和 国"},"confidence":"99","geoname_id":3175395}
```

when I try using to_json(), it produces this:

```
"{\"iso_code\":\"IT\",\"names\":{\"pt_br\":\"Itália\",\"es\":\"Italia\",\"ru\":\"Италия\",\"en\":\"Italy\",\"zh_cn\":\"意大利\",\"fr\":\"Italie\",\"de\":\"Italien\",\"ja\":\"イタリア共和国\"},\"confidence\":\"99\",\"geoname_id\":3175395}"
```

whose class is a string.

How can I convert it to a JSON or Hash form??. Thanks

Comment: The output of to_json is always a string. What output were you expecting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby to\_json issue with error "illegal/malformed utf-8"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067203/ruby-to-json-issue-with-error-illegal-malformed-utf-8)

Comment: I want it to be an hash. For example country.class = Hash, from the class Hashie::Rash.
..@fedorqui, this is not a duplicate question. they are not working with Hashie::Rash.

Comment: If you want a hash, you don't want it to be JSON.  It already is a hash, a [`Hashie::Rash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#rash) is just a souped-up `Hash` class.  Try `country['confidence']` and you should get `99`.

Comment: thanks nick for the suggestion but I know that it is possible, but I want to save it into a db after serializing or else by using postgres hstore variable. That is the reason I need it to be an hash.

Comment: JSON in ruby is just a string.  So if you want to store it in a db after serializing, `to_json` is the correct method to call, as it will store the JSON string.  Then when you pull the field back out, you would just de-serialize it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: I think that is working. But why can't serialize work? In my model I have serialize :country, Hash. And the table column is of type text. I am getting this error hashie::Rush to text error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have to_json format data look like:

```
str =  "{\"iso_code\":\"IT\",\"names\":{\"pt_br\":\"Itália\",\"es\":\"Italia\",\"ru\":\"Италия\",\"en\":\"Italy\",\"zh_cn\":\"意大利\",\"fr\":\"Italie\",\"de\":\"Italien\",\"ja\":\"イタリア共和国\"},\"confidence\":\"99\",\"geoname_id\":3175395}"
```

then go to terminal and require json and parse it like bellow:

```
require 'json'
ob = JSON.parse(str)
```

Then you get json formatted output there and this will be look like:

```
{"iso_code"=>"IT", "names"=>{"pt_br"=>"Itália", "es"=>"Italia", "ru"=>"Италия", "en"=>"Italy", "zh_cn"=>"意大利", "fr"=>"Italie", "de"=>"Italien", "ja"=>"イタリア共和国"}, "confidence"=>"99", "geoname_id"=>3175395}
```

Comment: I think that is working. But why can&#39;t serialize work? In my model I have serialize :country, Hash. And the table column is of type text. I am getting this error hashie::Rush to text error

Comment: @ben it's may be new issue, it wasn't in the log :) anyway if it's seems work then you can accept my answer. BTW, you can paste log in the other place then i can take a look on this and let you know.