# JSON::GeneratorError arising with the use of to_json method

Tags: json, ruby

I am getting the

> JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8

when I am using `to_json` method. I have not overridden the `to_json` method anywhere.

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067203/ruby-to-json-issue-with-error-illegal-malformed-utf-8) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583924/string-force-encoding-in-ruby-1-8-7-or-rails-2-x)

But as Ruby 1.8 does not have the concept of string encodings the solution is not helping me.

How can I solve this issue without the requirement to escape the specific non-ascii characters?

I am on ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Can you also provide a trivial simple test case to clarify what exactly you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The only Rails solution I am aware of would be:

```
# [AM] Monkeypatch to support multibyte utf-8
module ::ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding
  def self.escape(string)
    if string.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
      string = string.encode(
        ::Encoding::UTF_8,
        :undef => :replace
      ).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
    end
    json = string.gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }
    json = %("#{json}")
    json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) if json.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    json
  end
end
```

I believe there could be the same patch applied directly to `JSON::GeneratorError`.